# Array of undefinite length

Tags: algorithm, arrays, data-structures, binary-search

how to find a random element in a sorted array of unknown length.

Comment: You might want to give us more details, like the language you're using, what you already tried, ...

Comment: which programming language you need to do that in?

Comment: *Find a random element* sounds like picking a random element. But I assume you want to find a *specific* element in the array, right?

Comment: How can you not know the length of the array? How will you know that your index is out-of-boundaries?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'unknown length'?  Do you mean the length is *indeterminate* (meaning that you can't tell how long it is even at runtime, which seems unlikely) or that the length varies from one pass to the next?  In the second case, do you have an approximate min/max length?

Comment: -1,  the question is so unclear, and the author does not make any attempts to clarify - it should be closed

Comment: i want to know the algorithm, basically the pseudo code for the problem, so it's independent of language.

Comment: Voting to close -- at present the question is so unclear it's meaningless. The author has had an hour to clarify what he wants, but doesn't appear to have made any attempt to do so...

Comment: @mohit - you mention "the algorithm" and "the problem" - but people are trying to help tell you that the problem is not sufficiently defined at the momemt. You need to help by providing the clarification requested, otherwise it is meaningless to attempt to answer.

Comment: try reservoir sampling

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you mean `how do I find if an element is part of the array?` not `how do I return a random element from the array?`.

Use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) and assume that the length is very big (surely you have an upper bound?). If the middle element `m` you select at each step is outside the array bounds (you need a way to tell this), then limit the search to those elements with indexes small than `m`.

If you don't have a way to tell if an element is outside the bounds of the array then I don't see how you could solve this.

Comment: @Marc Gravell - I think that much is obvious from the question.

Comment: You are right; I missed that (removed, but for history: I commented about it needing to be sorted)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have something that you can loop, but you can't determine the length beforehand. You can get a random item by looping the items, and calculate the probability that the item should be picked.

C# example to pick an `int` (selected) from an `IEnumerable<int>` (items):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int cnt = 0;
int selected = 0;
foreach (int item in items) {
  if (rnd.Next(++cnt) == 0) {
    selected = item;
  }
}
```

At the first item, you get a random number between 0 and 0, which of course is 0, so you keep that item. At the second item, you get a random number between 0 and 1, and if it is 0, you keep the second item instead. And so on until you run out of items. For each additional item, the probability to keep that one instead gets lower, which is why the probability to end up with any specific item in the collection is the same.

Comment: This isn't an array though, and you don't use the fact that the elements are sorted.

Comment: @IVlad: The size of an array in .NET is always known, so that part doesn't really make sense. This solutions works for any collection that you can iterate. If you want to get a random item, it's completely irrelevant if the items are sorted or not.

Comment: +1: this is a good solution for choosing a random item from a stream of items. It can be easily proved (by induction) that at step N every item has a chance of 1/N to be chosen. 
(I don't know yet what is the relevance of the fact that the stream is sorted...)